# Whitelist for Internet Explorer without impacting other browsers

Tags: windows, internet-explorer-11

Has anyone found a way to limit IE to a specific set of sites without hamstringing other browsers or installing other software?  We still do need it for an increasingly smaller list of webpages.

Enterprise Mode site list manager does not allow wildcards, so it seems you can only tell IE which sites it should open, not which sites it cannot.

Chrome Enterprise and Legacy Browser Support (redirect to Chrome) works amazingly if you manage Chrome through Google Apps.  But on servers etc. it may not be practical to install Chrome Enterprise in managed mode with LBS.

Also pretty sure Content Advisor (which we never tried) is phased out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To only allow certain websites access internet in the IE browser, please refer to the following steps:

1. Use administrator to open Internet Explorer.  tap on the cog-shaped icon at the upper-right corner and select **Internet Options**.
2. On the Internet options menu window, navigate to **Connections** tab and click **LAN Settings**.
3. Check the '**Use a proxy server settings**' option which will enable the textbox for Address and Port number. All you have to do is enter the following address **`127.0.0.1`**. Let the port number stay as **80**.

[image]

4. Click on the **Advanced** button. You'll see that the addresses for HTTP and FTP will be already populated. Scroll down and enter the addresses of the sites which you want to whitelist. Make sure to enter the full addresses. Separate multiple addresses by a semicolon.

[image]

5. Once done, hit OK. Now, all the websites except the ones which you have whitelisted will be blocked in IE browser.